# spark read file with string column as factor (or enum)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have seen in pyspark you can define a schema to a file that is going to be read. One very simple example is below:

```
schema_input=StructType([StructField('some_string_column',StringType(),False)])
df=spark.read.schema(schema_input).option('header','true').csv(<path>)
```

Assuming I have a column that has only three possible string values (red,blue and yellow) but the dataframe is 1 billion rows long, isn't there a way to read as factors or enum to save some space/time?

I don't know if there's an equivalent `EnumType(<enum_list>)` to the `StringType()` data type. I have read the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/data_types.html) on pyspark datatypes and it only seems to understand strings as strings, there doesn't seems to be a something like reading as factors/enums to save space

One important note is that I am asking if it's possible to do this while reading time, not to encode the string column after it has been read.

Comment: can you please add input & output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a question on how the file is made in the first place. Spark **will** need to read your file, it can't skip over elements.

Imagine your example: you have a very simple dataset with 1 column and 1 billion rows. The only possible values are `red`, `blue` and `yellow`. As you correctly noticed, you could turn these into an enum to store these values more efficiently.

Imagine the following file (your file has 1 billion rows):

```
red
blue
yellow
red
```

Let's compare two approaches:

- you could encode each value with 2 bits (`red == 00`, `blue == 01`, `yellow == 11`)

```
00
01
11
00
```

- encode each char with their ASCII value

```
01110010 01100101 01100100
01100010 01101100 01110101 01100101
01111001 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 01110111
01110010 01100101 01100100
```

It's pretty clear that the first approach is much more concise than the second one.

#### BUT

Spark can't magically skip over these bits when reading your disk. It needs to read your whole file content to be able to know what the values are (imagine reading only the first 2 bits of **approach 2**, that would yield totally wrong results).

So that means you can't do your optimization, unless your file was properly written down to start with. And in that case, your issue is already solved! :)